# Prove by induction that $n < 2^n$ for all $n \ge 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I'm trying to do homework problems and for the most part I've been getting the results. For this one though, I am having some trouble since its $2^n$ and I can't relate it properly:

> Prove using simple induction that $n < 2^n$ for all $n \ge 1$.

So obviously, the basis step holds as $1 < 3$. Now, I assume that $n = k$ holds as well and have to prove for $n=k+1$. This is the step I am having trouble with as I cannot relate the induction hypothesis with what I want to end up with. Can anybody show me a model solution for this one? I think my trouble comes because of the $2^n $

Answer (score 3):

For the inductive step:

$$n+1\le 2n<2\times 2^n=2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

a hint: you need to show that 
$$ n + 1 < 2^{n+1}$$
observe that $$ 2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^{n} = 2^n + 2^n$$
now use your induction hypothesis to estimate $2^n$. also observe that $1$ is the smallest natural number, i.e. $1 \leq n$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. For all $n\ge 1$, $2^n>n>1$
2. $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n=2^n+2^n>2^n+1$

Answer (score 0):

Yo know that $k<2^k$ and you want to prove $k+1<2^{k+1}$, but it's equal:

$$k+1<2^{k+1}=2^k+2^k$$

By induction hipothesis you know that $k<2^k$ and on the other hand it's clear that $1 \leq 2^{k}$. If you add this inqeualities side by side you get $k+1<2^k+2^k=2^{k+1}$.